# DocuSign signing from app

Tags: node.js, docusignapi

I am building a NodeJS application in which I would like to integrate DocuSign API to get a PDF signed from the application. 
I tried the REST API as given in
https://developers.docusign.com/esign-rest-api/code-examples/signing-from-your-app

The problem is, it needs login from browser to generate the access token. Is there a way to login admin account through code?

EDIT:  I tried using API calls as mentioned in [link](https://developers.docusign.com/esign-rest-api/guides/features/embedding) using     POST /accounts/{accountId}/envelopes

Header: {Authorization: 'Bearer '+docusign_credentials.token},

My request body is:

```
{
  emailSubject: 'Please sign this document sent from Node SDK',
  documents:
   [{
       documentBase64: '*base64code****',
       name: 'TestFile.pdf',
       extension: 'pdf',
       documentId: '1' } ],
       recipients: {  signers: [ { 
                      email: 'ss@gmail.com',
                      name: 'ss',
                      recipientId: '1',
                      clientUserId: '1001',
                      tabs: { signHereTabs: [Array] } } ] },
                      status: 'sent' }
  }]
```

But, the result is

```
{ signers: [],
  agents: [],
  editors: [],
  intermediaries: [],
  carbonCopies: [],
  certifiedDeliveries: [],
  inPersonSigners: [],
  seals: [],
  recipientCount: '0' }
```

Is there a reason for missing signers in result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Login from browser for `Service Integration (using JWT)` is required if you are using `User Consent`, and it is required only once. If you want to avoid this `User Consent`, then you can use `Admin Consent`, but for that you need to claim your user's email domain in DocuSign and the `emaildomain` of the user should be the one which your Organization owns, it should not be @gmail.com or @yahoo.com etc as you will not be able to modify DNS entries for the email domains which you do not own. If you want to proceed with this `Admin Consent` approach then you need to check with your DocuSign Account Manager for the pricing/plans.

Comment: Is there any example of JWT using User Consent? I tried this example https://github.com/docusign/OAuth_JWT_recipes but it is failing at 'Step 4: Retrieve User Account Data' when using this url  'https://account-d.docusign.com/oauth/userinfo' to get account information.

Comment: What error you are getting? trying hitting `https://account-d.docusign.com/oauth/userinfo` in POSTMAN with your generated AccessToken and see if it returns the response.

Comment: It gives me Internal Server Error. Here is the response: {
    "error": "internal_server_error",
    "reference_id": "89ea892a-19b6-472d-9852-d69c28c62416"
}

Comment: I think you are getting 401 Unauthorized, either AccessToken you generated is not valid or has expired. Did you give proper User Consent with correct scopes, check [JWT Blog](https://www.docusign.com/blog/dsdev-using-the-oauth-jwt-flow/) for more details

Comment: CAn you check the edit section of post and guide me further. Thank you..